# Overwriting file failed due to permissions on Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, ftp, permissions, plesk

On a existing Laravel project I'm trying to upload a fix to the webserver. I have no experience with Laravel. The file I'm trying to overwrite is in `/app/libraries/`.

The FTP server has a `test.domain.com` and a live version in `httpdocs`. I am able to upload the fix in the test enviroment, but in the live enviroment I get permission denied in FileZilla. I even tried to use the File Manager on Plesk but even then I get `Permission denied`. The FTP user and the Plesk user both have all permissions possible.

I have permission to write in `/app/` but not in any subdirectory of `/app/`.

Is Laravel preventing to overwrite these files? Why is it working on the test version on the same webserver? Is there any other way to overwrite the file in that folder?

Comment: So what is the permissions on  /app/libraries and file in this folder?

Comment: @OlegNeumyvakin; Folder is chmodded 755 and file is 644. When trying to change I get `Operation not permitted`

Comment: **755** and **644** respectively, means only the owner of those directories/files has the write privilege. If the user you're connecting with over FPT is not the owner of those files, then you can't change them. Check the permissions/owner of the subfolders, such as `app/libraries`, and see if they match your user and the required privileges. Does anyone else perhaps uploaded the files using a different username?

Comment: @vonUbisch your problem has nothing to do with Laravel. This is actually a *FTP permissions* thing you should solve with help of the server administrator. If you are the only responsible of the server, then, have you got any other access like CPanel or server configuration ? Can you provide a screenshot of permissions of the files ?

Comment: Even when the FTP user has all rights if the PHP executor (webserver or php-fpm instance) isn't the same user and the executor hasn't any rights (not same group etc.) to do stuff you still have a problem. So my guess is that the user which executes your script(webserver or php-fpm instance) isn't allowed to execute it aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned by Trip, its nothing to do with Laravel and reply you got by Bogdan is definitely the correct one.

I recommend you talk with Server Admin to associate your user with permissions correct permissions to that folder. If your the owner of the server please read some kind of tutorials.

P.S. This one might help:
http://www.whoishostingthis.com/blog/2011/05/25/understanding-file-permissions-ftp-chmod/

Comment: The owner (non-tech) messed around with his VPS accounts in Plesk, after contacting the hosting support they did some magic and everything was back to normal. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

/app/libraries is not a folder that is a part of a base Laravel installation (at least not L4 or L5), so I would say this permission has nothing to do with Laravel itself.

Bogdan's comment is right on. The libraries subfolder is most likely owned by a user other than the one you're connecting with.